# Does C++/11 auto keyword deduce to parameters to pass-by-reference when that is more efficient, or always pass-by-value?

Tags: c++, auto

I'd like to know if C++ 'auto' is smart enough to pass by reference for [in] parameters.   For example:

```
   void PrintString(auto string1)
    {
        std::string msg;
        msg = string1 + "\n";
        printf("%s\n", msg.c_str());
    }
```

Is *auto* smart enough to deduce string1 type to a const ref type like this?

```
void PrintString(const std::string &string1)
```

or does it just deduce to inefficient pass-by-value?

```
void PrintString(std::string string1)
```

Comment: If you use `auto&& string1`.

Comment: Using `auto` in a function like so is not allowed by C++? It's probably a compiler extension. Best not to use it.

Comment: This is not valid C++. With move semantics pass-by-value is not always inefficient.

Comment: The semantics of using `auto` in a function for parameters is for lambda functions, which are template based under the covers.

Comment: @Evg [N4040](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4040.pdf) and its Generic Functions will most likely end up in C++20. Some compilers already support them.

Comment: BTW, with inlining, and optimization, compiler might avoid your copy from pass by value. Wonder why you have extra `msg` to append twice `\n` to the printing of `string1`...

Comment: @Swordfish, good to hear. But we have to wait. Some compilers support very fascinating features, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AfRAVcThyA, but we can't really use them now.

Comment: passing by value is more efficient than passing by reference in this case, all things considered (mutating the string inside the function)

Comment: Not sure whether `auto` on normal functions will make things easier for beginners (`auto` on lambda was possibly already confusing)

Comment: @curiousguy: It all depends on how `auto` is taught. If you start with template functions and then teach them a simpler way to write them, then it should be fine. If you start with `auto` parameters, then problems will arise.

Comment: __italic__Wonder why you have extra msg to append twice \n to the printing of string1 I was just trying to construct an artificial example, not real code. __italic__

I didnt make it complex enough so you guys are pointing out pass-by-value actually is better for this particular case :)

Answer (score 3):

`auto` as applied to function parameters is illegal in C++11, so your question is moot.

C++14 allows *lambda* functions to use `auto` in parameters. But this is done by making the lambda's generated `operator()` a template. So `[](auto val)` is equivalent to `template<typename T> void some_func(T val);`. And just like any other instance of a template, `val` is not a reference unless `T` is itself a reference type. The rules of template argument deduction don't change just because you used `auto` rather than an explicit template argument.

The same will be true when/if C++20 formally allows `auto` to work on all functions. And compilers which offer `auto` parameters on non-lambdas as a compiler extension are doing it exactly as they would for lambdas.

---

> Is *auto* smart enough to deduce string1 type to a const ref type like this?

What about this would be "smart"? The user didn't ask for a `const&` parameter, as evidenced by the lack of `const` and the lack of `&`. If a user genuinely wants the so-called "inefficient" version (which is a perfectly valid thing to do), then such code would not be smart. Indeed, under your "smart" version, you would be *unable* to write a function that took `std::string` by value.